# Windows Phone XAP Obfuscation with ConfuserEx

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, obfuscation

We have came accross a requirement where we need to obfuscate windows phone application (`.xap`) file.

We are looking for an open source tool which can do basic obfuscation for an `.xap` file.

After little search we found `ConfuserEx`.This tool as of now support `.dll` and `.exe` obfuscation.

Can i obfuscate `.xap` file with this tool is my question.

Options i have tried so far is have extracted `.xap` file and put `.dll` files to obfuscate but it gives following error?

```
[ERROR] Failed to resolve dependency of 'MyApp.dll'.
Exception: dnlib.DotNet.AssemblyResolveException: Could not resolve assembly: Microsoft.Phone, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24eec0d8c86cda1e
   at dnlib.DotNet.Extensions.ResolveThrow(IAssemblyResolver self, IAssembly assembly, ModuleDef sourceModule) in E:\Source\Public\Confuser2\dnlib\src\DotNet\IAssemblyResolver.cs:line 113
   at Confuser.Core.ConfuserEngine.Inspection(ConfuserContext context) in e:\Source\Public\Confuser2\Confuser.Core\ConfuserEngine.cs:line 254
Failed at 3:09 PM, 0:00 elapsed.
```

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Confuserex to obfuscate xap file like you, I use Crypto Obfuscator, and I meet the same bug, too.

```
Exception: dnlib.DotNet.AssemblyResolveException: Could not resolve assembly: Microsoft.Phone, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24eec0d8c86cda1e
```

So it take me 1h to work around and found that I need to make a reference to file Microsoft.Phone.dll (in Crypto Obfuscator)

> Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\

Hope it works with your case.